# Can't exit PhoneGap Build application

Tags: javascript, android, phonegap-build

I've been doing a whole bunch of looking around, but I can't seem to find anything that's helped so far.

Basically I can't exit my app no matter what I try.

I've tried:

```
navigator.app.exitApp();
&
app.exitApp();
```

On both:

```
$("#myButton").click(function(){..
&
<a id="close" onClick="myFunction">Exit</a>
```

I'm getting to the end of my ropes here, thoughts? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Android. I'm fully aware that iOS doesn't support exiting the app.

Comment: Well then good! Your code is fine, maybe you should post more of the HTML...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to answer this myself. My issue was that I was lacking a deviceready listener and instead calling the function in a document ready.